# Why the text is separated in some devices with fontSize: 25? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have an about component that just render two text component, this is the code:

```
 class about extends Component {
    
    render() {
   
        return (
        <>
            <View style = {this.styles.container}>
                <Text style = {this.styles.text}>Hi</Text>
                <Text style = {this.styles.text}>A very simple notebloc.</Text>
            </View>
        </>
        );
    }

    styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            marginTop: - Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.5) / 2,
            flexDirection: "column"
        },
        text: {
            fontSize: 25,
            fontFamily: "serif",
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "#1E90FF",
        }
    })
}
```

pertty simple, the problem now, is that I want them with `FontSize: 25` but when I taste it in real devices, in some of them the second text is separated, gonna post some screen so you can see the issue:

this is how I want it works in all devices:

[image]

but in some devices I get this:

[image]

how can I solve this? I set the `fontSize` to 24 and I think it will work in all devices, but when its in 25, it doesnt, something to add, the first image is a device that the `width` is bigger than the second one, so I think the `width` isnt the problem

Answer (score 0):

To solve that, try to use `react-native-size-matters` to scale the font size no matter the device pixel density.

For example

```
fontSize: moderateScale(24, 0.3)
```